# Prove that $xy=yx$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a group and $f,g:G\rightarrow G,f(x)=x^6,g(x)=x^{10}$ are homomorphisms, where $f$ is injective. Prove that $xy=yx$.

We know that$(xy)^{10}=x^{10}y^{10},(xy)^{6}=x^{6}y^{6},(xy)^{9}=y^{9}x^{9},(xy)^{5}=y^{5}x^{5},x^{9}y^{10}=y^{10}x^{9}$ and $x^{5}y^{6}=y^{6}x^{5}$, but I couldn't use these results in a productive way.

Comment: This is false in any nonabelian group of exponent $5$, since then $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=1$ for all $x \in G$.

Comment: +1 @Derek: Great comment.  I was flowing in silly computations without noticing this. (If $g$ is also assumed to be injective, then it is doable. $x^5y^6(x^5)^{-1}=y^6$ so $x^5$ commutes with all $y$. Also $x^9y^{10}(x^9)^{-1}=y^{10}$ implies $x^9$ commutes with all $y$. It now follows that $x$ commutes with all $y$.)

Comment: Either  there is a mistake in the problem statement, or the problem was actually to decide whether this is true of false. You can waste a lot of time trying to prove false results!

Comment: Did you mean to say that both $f$ and $g$ are injective?

Comment: No, $g$ was not supposed to be injective, but surely this is the mistake of this statement.

Answer (score 3):

This statement is false. Take $UT(3, 5)$ as a counterexample. Any other non-abelian group of exponent $5$ will do too.